# Where to query model if not in model.py?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model.py that looks as such:

```
from django.db import models
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import date 
from datetime import timedelta
import time

class cryptoData(models.Model):
    coin = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    asset_id = models.SmallIntegerField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()
    market_cap = models.FloatField()
    reddit_posts = models.IntegerField()
    reddit_comments = models.IntegerField()
    tweets = models.IntegerField()
    tweet_favorites = models.IntegerField()
    social_volume = models.IntegerField()

def apiFunc():
      #pull data from API and put into df
     return(df)
 
df = apiFunc()


cryptoData.objects.bulk_create(
    cryptoData(**vals) for vals in df.to_dict('records')
)
```

However, as I understand from reviewing other threads, it is not in best practice to query the database in the same file as model.py. Where then should I house the code that loads data into my created model?

Comment: I am not super expert in django. As I understood I think you are asking about the `get_query`. If it's true then you have to create a view.py.

Comment: I'm more referring to the 'bulk_create' I do to load the data into the model.

Comment: what kind of data do you refer to? an existing one or comes from the user?

Comment: just create a separate file for api pull and import models into it.

Answer (score 1):

Django has MVT design pattern, Similar to MVC

> M: Model - database tables and their fields,
> V: View - all requests come to here and you query data and save them to the db, > T: Template - html template

So if you have any request like get, post, put etc. you should create functions which are connected with urls.py. Django has 2 options like function based view and class based view, you can use one of them. At the beginning I recommend you to use function based view, write your get and create functions. Don't forget to import your functions on the urls.py. Coming requests will trigger one of the these functions and you can save data into db. Also don't forget to import your db tables (from models.py) on the views.py